# Text not rotating on its center

Tags: c#, winforms, text

I am trying to rotate the text on its center. But my code produces the output like this when rotating. I can't get the right point for the **Matrix to RotateAt**:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
using (StringFormat string_format = new StringFormat())
        {
            SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, _fontStyle);
            rect.Location = new PointF(Shape.center.X - (rect.Width / 2), Shape.center.Y - (rect.Height / 2));
            GraphicsContainer gc = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(rect));

            RectangleF r = new RectangleF(rect.Location, rect.Size);
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            if (text == "" || text == " ")
                path.Dispose(); //Disposes the path to prevent OutOfMemoryExcetption
            else
            {
                path.AddString(text, _fontStyle.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(_fontStyle.Style), _fontStyle.Height, new Point(0,0), string_format);
                RectangleF text_rectf = path.GetBounds();
                PointF[] target_pts = {
                            new PointF(r.Left, r.Top),
                            new PointF(r.Right, r.Top),
                            new PointF(r.Left, r.Bottom)};
                //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(r));
                using (Matrix m = new Matrix(text_rectf, target_pts)) 
                using (Matrix rotate = new Matrix())
                using (Matrix FlipXMatrix = new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)) 
                using (Matrix FlipYMatrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0))
                using (Matrix TransformMatrix = new Matrix())
                {
                    TransformMatrix.Multiply(m);
                    m.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(0 + (stringSize.Width / 2), +(r.Height * 2)));
                    rotate.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(r.X, r.Y));
                    TransformMatrix.Multiply(rotate);
                    if (flipped)
                    {
                        TransformMatrix.Multiply(FlipXMatrix);
                    }
                    path.Transform(TransformMatrix);

                    if (flipY)
                    {
                        TransformMatrix.Multiply(FlipYMatrix);
                        path.Transform(TransformMatrix);
                    }

                    //Checks if the user wants the text filled or outlined
                    if (!isOutlined)
                        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, path);
                    else
                        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path);
                } 
            }
        e.Graphics.EndContainer(gc);
        }
```

PS. The rectangle is drawn just for my reference.

Comment: Is it string or image.?

Comment: Please tidy your code and your question if you want people to answer you. When I tried to read your code I ended up with mostly things that are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Toucanite I'm working on the functions first before re organizing the code. but well, you're right, the messy code might have been the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the fix or rather made a way to fix it. The error is caused by the transformations of the matrices. They should be in correct order.

```
using (StringFormat string_format = new StringFormat())
        {
            SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, _fontStyle);
            rect.Location = new PointF(Shape.center.X - (rect.Width / 2), Shape.center.Y - (rect.Height / 2));
            GraphicsContainer gc = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(rect));

            RectangleF r = new RectangleF(rect.Location, rect.Size);
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            if (text == "" || text == " ")
                path.Dispose(); //Disposes the path to prevent OutOfMemoryExcetption
            else
            {
                path.AddString(text, _fontStyle.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(_fontStyle.Style), _fontStyle.Height, new Point(0,0), string_format);
                RectangleF text_rectf = path.GetBounds();
                PointF[] target_pts = {
                            new PointF(r.Left, r.Top),
                            new PointF(r.Right, r.Top),
                            new PointF(r.Left, r.Bottom)};
                using (Matrix m = new Matrix(text_rectf, target_pts)) 
                using (Matrix rotate = new Matrix())
                using (Matrix FlipXMatrix = new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 500, 0)) 
                using (Matrix FlipYMatrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 500))
                using (Matrix TransformMatrix = new Matrix())
                {
                    rotate.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(250,250));
                    TransformMatrix.Multiply(rotate);
                    if (flipped)
                        TransformMatrix.Multiply(FlipXMatrix);
                    TransformMatrix.Multiply(m);
                    path.Transform(TransformMatrix);
                    if (!isOutlined)
                        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, path);
                    else
                        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, path);
                } 
            }
        e.Graphics.EndContainer(gc);
        }
```

> Rotation of matrix first, then the flipping, then the final drawing. **Matrix.Mulitply** also helped.